# npm install AND npm run dev Returns npm ERR! code E404

Tags: php, laravel, npm, laravel-9

I just downloaded Laravel 9 and tried to run `npm run save && npm run dev` but this error occurs on the Terminal:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/AND - not_found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'AND@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 This package name is not valid, because
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User 1\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-17T09_18_19_657Z-debug-0.log
```

So what's going wrong here?

I tried running `npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry` but again the error appears!

So what's going wrong here?

How can I solve this issue?

### UPDATE #1:

**`package.json`**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: it tries to install a package named `AND`. show your package.json

Comment: @derpirscher I've just updated my question

Comment: `npm run save` should run a script save, but I don't see a script like that in your `package.json`. Can you tell us what kind of script it is?

Comment: This isn't the default `package.json` that comes with laravel 9. How did you install laravel in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to reinstall Laravel
If the error still persists, try testing with vpn again

Answer (score 0):

Try removing .npmrc file and reinstalling node. Hope it works :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).